# Resource Error when connecting dremio to Alteryx

Tags: connector, alteryx, dremio

I've data that is on `Dremio` and I'm looking to connect it with Alteryx.

It was working fine until once I had cancelled the Alteryx workflow in the middle of the execution. After that that instance - it is always giving the below error which I'm not able to figure out why.

```
Error: Input Data (1): Error SQLExecute: [Dremio][Connector] (1040) Dremio failed to execute the query: SELECT * FROM "Platform_Reporting"."PlatformActivity" limit 1000
[30039]Query execution error. Details:[ 
RESOURCE ERROR: Query cancelled by Workload Manager. Query enqueued time of 300.00 seconds exceeded for 'High Cost User Queries' queue.

[Error Id: 3a1e1bb0-18b7-44c0-965a-6933a156ab70 ]
```

[image]
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I got this response from the Alteryx Support team:

Based on the error message it seems the error sit within Dremio itself I would advice to consult the admin to check: https://docs.dremio.com/advanced-administration/workload-management/

I would assume the cancellation of a previous pipeline was not send accordingly to the queue management and thus the error.